# Self Selection bias for estimating a valiable correlated to the selector

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, bias, causality

I am trying to find a way to see if a measured variable between two groups is significantly different. This would normally be done through a t-test if the two groups were randomly selected from the population. However, in my case the two group are not randomly selected. They are selected by a binary variable which is strongly correlated to the measured variable.

As a toy example say we are trying to find if having a profile on an e-commerce site **causes** users to spend more. If we look at the two groups (with and without a profile) there is a statistically significant greater mean spend by the group who has a profile. However we know that users that expect to spend often are more likely to set up an account in the first place since they are more engaged. Is there a way to compensate for this so that one could confidently assert that encouraging users to create a profile is likely to increase revenue for the e-commerce site?

Comment: I think the most straightforward and intuitive way is to take a Bayesian approach. That is: use what knowledge or assumptions you have regarding the correlation of the binary selection variable with the measured variable to define a suitable prior, and proceed from there.

Comment: This question may best be answered by an experiment. For example, randomly encourage half your participants to establish profiles. If your encouragement is effective, then look at the amount spent by group.

Comment: @RyanSimmons Unless I misunderstand this would rely on accurate modelling of which users will self select. In the above example this would be which users make a profile. This is not possible in many cases.

Comment: @JoelW. Yes a split test would surely solve this issue. What you would want is to only allow a random set of users to see or create a profile and then they would have a different user experience where profiles did not exist. This is the industry standard approach for all such problems. I was hoping there was an analytical solution.

Comment: The decision on how to analyze your data will involve judgement about how the variables are operating: what relationships may be reasonably thought to be operating or not, and which may be ignored by the analysis.  Do you want to tell us more or do you want us to stick to your hypothetical example?

Comment: Maybe another example would be instructive. Say we are trying to see if the Stack Exchange sign-in method (Facebook, google+ or SE itself) changes the quality of the posts given. The hypothesis would be that Facebook and Google signed in users are more inclined to give good answers because they are more personally linked to them. However, there would be a self selection bias coming from the original choice of sign-in.

Comment: @Keith In your latest example, if you are interested in knowing if sign-in method predicts quality, why are you concerned that there is self-selection into the sign-in methods?  Perhaps what we are experiencing here shows, again, the limitation of using an analogy rather than the actual situation.

Comment: I strongly believe that instrumental variable analysis (if you can find an instrument) is a good and relatively simple solution to your dilemma.  An instrument may either be fabricated from the variables already in the model or obtained elsewhere.  However, to come up with a good instrument we would need to know more about the data.  In the toy example, is the data cross-sectional or panel (panel is better), and are there any other consumer characteristics in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're essentially asking about the problem of making a [causal inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_inference) from observational data (since you mention in your comments that you don't want to perform experiments).

This problem is in general very tough, and the tools we have currently are not very solid or trustworthy. That being said, there are several different possible angles of attack, like  [instrumental variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_variable), [regression discontinuity designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_discontinuity_design), [difference-in-differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_in_differences), etc.

For instance, in your ecommerce website example, if they introduced some feature at one point that made people more likely to fill out their profiles when they signed up, you could use this as an instrumental variable to see whether people who signed up right before the change vs. right after had different buying behavior.

These types of analysis are not nearly as trustworthy as a truly randomized experiment, since it's somewhat tricky to get them right and make sure the assumptions are satisfied. But they can provide better evidence for causation than a simple regression analysis.